# using Plack::Middleware::DBIC::QueryLog with Dancer webapp

Tags: perl, dancer, plack

I am trying to use [Plack::Middleware::DBIC::QueryLog](http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Plack-Middleware-DBIC-QueryLog-0.05/lib/Plack/Middleware/DBIC/QueryLog.pm) inside of a dancer application.
The documentation tells me to get the querylog like this:

```
use Plack::Middleware::DBIC::QueryLog;
sub get_querylog_from_env {
  my ($self, $env) = @_;
  Plack::Middleware::DBIC::QueryLog->get_querylog_from_env($env);
}
```

In my dancer app before accessing my database schema I have to set `$schema->storage->debugobj`
to the `QueryLogger`.
My question is: How can I access the environment `$env` provided by Plack which contains the QueryLog object I'm
supposed to use?

I am starting my dancer application with

```
plackup bin/app.pl
```

where `app.pl` contains the default

```
use Dancer;
use app;
dance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
request->env();
```

from within your app.pm itself?  See [Dancer::Request](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer%3a%3aRequest#env-).  It's not a Plack::Request object, but judging from the source, it does contain PSGI ENV vars.

Comment: Thats it thank you. I thought I thouroughly read the Dancer::Request documentation. I somehow must have missed this obvious feature. Thank you!